# Center main menu headers in header of website

Tags: html, css

I have created a header with one div as a main menu of website and added into it some divs as main menu items. My question is: how to center vertically and horizontally inner divs which are headers of main menu placed in main menu items? I have tried many solutions like transformations and flex style of display but unfortunately nothing works. Why there is not something like Horizontal / VerticalAlignment from XAML in CSS?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#main-menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: inherit;
}

.main-menu-item {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: inherit;
}

.main-menu-header {
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
}

.main-submenu {
  width: inherit;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /*display: none;*/
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="main-menu">
      <div class="main-menu-item" onmouseover="ChangeDisplayOfSelectedSubmenu(0, 'block')" onmouseout="ChangeDisplayOfSelectedSubmenu(0, 'none')">
        <div class="main-menu-header">MenuItem1</div>
        <ul class="main-submenu">
          <li>SubMenuItem1</li>
          <li>SubMenuItem2</li>
          <li>SubMenuItem3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="main-menu-item" onmouseover="ChangeDisplayOfSelectedSubmenu(1, 'block')" onmouseout="ChangeDisplayOfSelectedSubmenu(1, 'none')">
        <div class="main-menu-header">MenuItem2</div>
        <ul class="main-submenu">
          <li>SubMenuItem1</li>
          <li>SubMenuItem2</li>
          <li>SubMenuItem3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="main-menu-item" onmouseover="ChangeDisplayOfSelectedSubmenu(2, 'block')" onmouseout="ChangeDisplayOfSelectedSubmenu(2, 'none')">
        <div class="main-menu-header">MenuItem3</div>
        <ul class="main-submenu">
          <li>SubMenuItem1</li>
          <li>SubMenuItem2</li>
          <li>SubMenuItem3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the padding top and padding bottom simply?

Try the CSS line-height Property Follor this : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

You can use a css old trick, use this:

```
header{
    height:50px;
    display:block;
}

#main-menu{
    position:aboslute;
    top:50px;
    margin-top:-25px;
}
```

Comment: It makes main menu not centered but docked to left margin of website. Also text in headers is not centered.

Comment: add width:100%; and margin:auto; and it should work perfectly!

Comment: could you provide a link so we can help you much better?

Comment: Sorry I can not add link because my hosting make website's look completly different than normally, it is screenshot after your last sugesiton: https://zapodaj.net/96cc6340401d6.png.html

Comment: Looks nice but text in headers is still not centered vertically and horizontally

Comment: Good luck, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to the following -

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

#main-menu {
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.main-menu-item {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    /* height: 100%; */
    text-align: center;
}

.main-menu-header {
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
}

.main-submenu {
  width: inherit;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  /*display: none;*/
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Using flexbox property here to achieve the desired effect

Comment: Text in headers is centered perfectly but unfortunately submenu items are placed in headers, not docked to bottom of them